# Undefined method uploading apk with Fastlane

Tags: android, gitlab-ci, google-fabric, fastlane

I'm getting an error on gitlab ci server deploying/uploading an apk to Fabric with Fastlane. The strange thing is that it is working if I run the task from my local. The Fastlane is the same version in both cases 2.123.0.

The method of the task that is failing is:

```
31 desc "Generate QA release notes"
32 private_lane :qa_release_notes do 
33 commit = last_git_commit 
34 short_hash = commit[:abbreviated_commit_hash] 
35 author = commit[:author] 
36 message = commit[:message] 
37 "Release notes of commit " + short_hash + " by " + author +":\n " + message 
38 end
```

And the error printed in the ci log is:

```
[15:43:34]: Error in your Fastfile at line 34
[15:43:34]: 32:  private_lane :qa_release_notes do
[15:43:34]: 33:  commit = last_git_commit
[15:43:34]: => 34:   short_hash = commit[:abbreviated_commit_hash]
[15:43:34]: 35:  author = commit[:author]
[15:43:34]: 36:  message = commit[:message]
```

(...)

```
Fastfile:34:in block (2 levels) in parsing_binding': [!] undefined method []' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.123.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
```

It seems the problem is with the method `commit[:abbreviated_commit_hash]`
But I don't know what the problem is...Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was the `last_git_commit` was getting an empty result (as @janpio said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56365444/888900)) because for some reason the `git` was missing in the Docker image.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message tells you that `commit = last_git_commit` didn't actually set `commit` to anything, so using `[...]` on it raises `[!] undefined method []' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`.

You could try to debug by simply outputting `commit` between lines 33 and 34: `puts(commit)`. Running the lane with `--verbose` might also give some additional, hopefully helpful output to understand what is going on.

The code being executed in the background is actually https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/4c468b9873f9a2bd68e8ef21b2502d32f2024d32/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/git_helper.rb#L53-L74, but I don't see an obvious way why this would be failing on gitlab CI.

Comment: Yes, it seems `last_git_commit` is not working fine... I'll investigate why. Thanks.

Comment: IDK why `git` was missing in the Docker image.